# I Want to add check box for every table row in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js

I Want to add check box for every table row in angular js and on checking it should pass the value to the controller,can someone guide me how to achieve it??

Here is my index1.html

```
<html ng-app>
<title>Angular Table</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/tableController.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-grid.css" />
<script src="JS/angtest.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="testcontroller">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>first name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>last name :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" ng-click="add(firstname,lastname)"
                value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>My first Table
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="names in nameslist">
            <td>{{names.firstname}} <!-- <input type="text" name="Id" ng-model="names.id"/>  -->
            </td>
            <td>{{names.lastname}} <!-- <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="names.name"/> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>count:</td>
            <td>{{count()}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my angtest.js

```
var testcontroller=function($scope){


    $scope.nameslist =[];   
    $scope.add = function(fname,lname){
        $scope.nameslist.push(new user(fname,lname) );
    };

    $scope.count = function(){
         return $scope.nameslist.length;
    };
};
function user(a,b)
{
    this.firstname=a;
    this.lastname=b;
}
```

this is my tableController.js

```
var myAngApp =angular.module('angularTableApp',[]);
myAngApp.controller('tableController',function($scope){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the ng-change directive, the rest is similar to your previous code.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="names in nameslist">
              ... //previous td's
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo" ng-change="changeValue(foo)"/> </td>

        </tr>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.changeValue = function(foo) {
     console.log(foo);
 }
```

You don't have to explicitly pass `foo` as a parameter since the `ng-model` directive will create the foo property on your `$scope` implicitly, but it's suggested to do so anyway since the `changeValue` function will now be more reusable.

Comment: How should i bind the row value to foo?

Comment: What do you mean by the row value? Anything you put into ng-model binds to your scope

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="names in nameslist">
        <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="names.firstname" /> </td>
    </tr>
```